# PHP MongoDB query dynamic values

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I want to query the content (text) inside my `dynamic values keys`, but i can't figure out the easiest way to do this.

So my mongo collection is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566aecb8f0e46491068b456c"),
    "metadatas" : [
        {
            "schema_id" : "f645fabef0e464e51e8b4567",
            "values" : {
                "name" : "Test",
                "age" : NumberLong(29),
                "address" : "Test1"
            },
            "updated_on" : ISODate("2015-12-11T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "schema_id" : "d745fabef0e464e51e8b4567",
            "values" : {
                "something_else" : "lipsum"
            },
            "updated_on" : ISODate("2016-12-11T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ],
}
```

How can i dynamically query whats inside my `values` since i cannot do `$db->collec->find(array('metadatas.values.name' => $regex))` because i might have some other dynamic key instead of name?

thanks in advance

Comment: if you have some other dynamic keys then you can use $and in mongodb. check : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: @Monty the problem is that i don't know the key names unless i iterate all collections to get all available keys and then build the query but i am worried about performance

Comment: In which case you might be better off transferring to a structure where you can query key names

Comment: @Sammaye that is actually a pretty good idea i think. i was querying all my existing files to collect the key names but now with that the number of elements to iterate is much smaller. definitely trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up saving my keys uniquely on another collection and then building the query and concatenating it before applying based on @Sammaye idea:

```
    $regex = new \MongoRegex("/^$query/i");

    # First get all the dynamic keys you need to filter
    $keys_to_search = $this->db->metadata_keys->find();
    $this->log($keys_to_search);

    $query_builder = array('$or'=>array());

    foreach ($keys_to_search as $value){
        array_push(
            $query_builder['$or'],
            array('metadatas.values.' . $value['key'] => $regex)
        );
    }

    $this->log($query_builder);

    $search_metadata_name = $this->db->filesfolders->find(
        $query_builder, array('sql_fileid' => true)
    );
```